# To copy only a part of a strip

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I want to copy a 3.5 minute sequece from a movie of about 2 hours, because I want to subtitle it and use it for a lecture of my own. I used the knife tool to cut away everything before and after this sequece. However , I am not able to copy it (Ctrl C) and paste it on anther track. There are no handles on the little sequence and the timeline stays the same: I do not manage to have my little strip starting at position zero. It is a free video, no copyright problems.
It is only the second time thet I work with the video editor, I am relatively new to Blender and use version 2.79.
Thanks to anybody who can help,
Jos

Answer (score 1):

Use Duplicate Strips. You'll find it in the Strip menu:

[image]

If you can't select a strip, then it may be too small and you can use the horizontal scrollbar handles to zoom in. After that, you just select it and drag it to where you want it.

To make sure you only render the part with a strip, use this function to limit the render range:
[image]

Comment: Hi, this worked. I was able to duplicate the short strips, but there were no handles.Burt View>View selected added them and I could proceed. Then I have copied and pasted both strips ( video and sound) to a new file using the Ctrl C and Ctrl V buttons on the lower control bar of the VSE. Thanks a lot , guys.  Jos

Answer (score 0):

In blender its shift + d to duplicate an object, it's the same with VSE
select the strip and press shift + d. You can do this manually in blender 2.8 by going to the strip tab -> duplicate strip.
[image]